# Understanding linkage of identifiers

Tags: c, enums, linkage

I'm reading [the Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf): [N1570](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) and came across some misunderstanding. I wrote the following simple example:

`test.h`:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

extern int second;

#endif //TEST_H
```

`test.c`:

```
#include "test.h"

enum test_enum{ 
    first,
    second
};
```

But it fails to compile with the error:

```
error: ‘second’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
     second
     ^~~~~~
```

This is strange, because Section `6.4.4.3#2` specifies:

> 2 An identifier declared as an enumeration constant has type int.

I our case the enumeration constant has file scope so I expected it to compile fine.

I rewrote the example above as follows:
`main.c`:

```
extern int second;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Second: %d\n", second);
}
```

And now linker complains:

```
undefined reference to `second'
```

Why? It should find the definition in the `test.c` because as the `Section 6.2.2#5` specifies:

> If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and
>   no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.

Comment: You may also reference the web page holding the [C11 Standard - Draft n1570](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) to prevent having everyone download the entire `.pdf` each time (both are fine, just a suggestion)

Comment: You are including `test.h` which contains `extern int second;` When you declare an `enum`, the label (enum members) are also *global constants* -- the compiler sees two declarations of `second` -- thus the redeclaration.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The problem is if I replace the declaration of enumeration constant with `int` it works as expected.

Comment: Either move the `enum` to the header and include `test.h` in main, or rename the variable `second` to something else in `test.h` and define it in `test.c`.

Comment: The first snippet would require the notion of different namespaces for different types so the identifier is not ambiguous.  C only has that for struct members.  Early K&R didn't, very painful.  Notable that C++ fixed that just recently with enum class.  The second snippet has extern ("it lives somewhere else") in all the code, the linker correctly complains "where?"  Delete extern in the main.c file to say "here".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Objects and Constants Are Different Things

Your citation of 6.4.4.3 2, that an enumeration constant has type `int`, suggests you think that because `extern int second` and `enum { second }` declare `second` to be an `int`, that these two declarations of `second` may refer to the same thing. That is not correct.

`extern int second` declares `second` to be the name of an object (a region of memory) that will hold an `int`. `enum { second }` declares `second` to be an enumeration constant which will have a particular value. The enumeration constant has no object (no memory) associated with it. An `int` object and an `int` constant are different things, and you may not use the same identifier for them in the same scope.

## Not All Declarations Are Definitions

Regarding your question about the link error, “undefined reference to ‘second’”, although `test.c` may contain `external int second` (since it is provided by the included `test.h`, this is not a definition of `second`. It is only a declaration, which tells the compiler that the name refers to an object. It does not define the object. Alternatively, if `test.c` contains `enum { second }`, this only declares `second` to be a constant. It does not define an object.

The rules for what is a definition are a bit complicated due to the history of programming language development. For identifiers of objects declared at file scope, there are essentially four cases:

- A declaration with `extern` is only a declaration, not a definition. Example: `extern int second;`.
- A declaration with an initializer is a definition. Example: `int second = 2;`.
- A declaration without `extern` and without an initializer is a tentative definition. If no definition appears in the translation unit (source file being compiled, with all included files), the tentative definition becomes a definition. Example: `int second;`.

The linkage is not helpful here. The `extern int second` in `test.c` and the `extern int second` in `main.c` may refer to the same object due to linkage, but no object for them to refer to was defined. Or, in the alternative, if `test.c` contains `enum { second }`, then it does not define an object named `second`, so there is no object that the `extern int second` in `main.c` can refer to.

Comment: Why isn't enumeration constant not an object? Section 3.15 specifies that object is `region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent
values` Nothing is about enum here... Or is it specified that enumeration constant/constant is not an object?

Comment: @St.Antario: Per C 2018 6.2.5 16, an enumeration is a set of named integer values. So an enumeration constant is just a name for a value. It is not a name for a region of memory. When you use it in source code, the compiler’s only obligation is to treat it as that value—it has no obligation to reserve memory for it. Also, it has no address. You can take the address of an object, but you cannot take the address of an enumeration constant.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you are attempting, you simply need to refactor you code a bit so that `test.[ch]` does not see a redeclaration of `second`. The problem is the symbol `second` is defined once as `extern int second;` and then again as the symbol within the `enum`. You can't have both visible within the same file.

To do that you can write `test1.h` using a second preprocessor conditional similar to:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#ifdef USE_ENUM
    enum test_enum{
        first,
        second
    };
#else
    extern int second;
#endif

#endif
```

Where depending on whether `USE_ENUM` is defined, the code will use either the symbol provided by the `enum`, where if not, then you need to *define* `second` in `test1.c`

```
#include "test1.h"

#ifdef USE_ENUM
    char stub (void)    /* stub to prevent empty compilation unit */
    { return 0; }
#else
    int second = 2;
#endif
```

(note the use of a `stub` function to prevent an *empty compilation unit* if `USE_ENUM` is defined -- as there would be no code in `test1.c` otherwise)

Now all that is required is to include `test1.h` in your file containing `main()` and passing the compiler define `-DUSE_ENUM` as a compiler option depending on which code you want to use, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test1.h"

int main (void) {

    printf ("second: %d\n", second);

}
```

**Compile Using `int second` defined in `test.c`**

Example:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -o bin/main1 main1.c test1.c
```

**Example Use/Output**

When `USE_ENUM` is not defined, then the definition of `second` defined in `test1.c` and accessed via `extern` will result in `second` having the value `2`, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/main1
second: 2
```

**Compile Using `enum` defined in `test.h`**

Example:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -o bin/main1 main1.c test1.c -DUSE_ENUM
```

**Example Use/Output**

When `USE_ENUM` is defined, then the value for the symbol `second` is provided by the `enum` in `test1.h`, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/main1
second: 1
```

While this is a slight refactoring of what you were attempting, I don't see another way of doing both without using the preprocessor conditional.